# Can't customise color of material-ui RaisedButton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the color of the material-ui RaisedButton using inline style customisation using backgroundColor: '#fb933c', but it's still showing the default color.

Comment: Do you mean `FloatButton` or `FloatingActionButton`? Could you paste your code?

Comment: I am using a RaisedButton. I'm having trouble pasting my code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use build-in `backgroundColor` property.

```
<RaisedButton
   backgroundColor="#fb933c"
/>
```

Comment: Question asked for `RaisedButton`, but answer is the same.